# Grafana. Can you split one-field one-row table with json value into multiple fields and rows in Grafana table dashboard?

Tags: json, extract, grafana, zabbix

I was trying to figure out, how to extract fields and rows from a single text field in the table in Grafana. Still had no luck.
I'm monitoring Sql Database with Zabbix.
I have an item in Zabbix, that returns a JSON-string as a single text string.
I had to do it this way, because, apparently, Zabbix can not return you a set of database rows.

I want to have a table in Grafana with dynamic number of rows to monitor current data in database.
Before that, it worked through SQL-authentification and there was a single SQL datasource that enabled me to write query directly for Grafana table dashboard.
But right now I have to do it through windows authentification and Zabbix datasource.

`JSON https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMsjL.png`

`Dashboard datasource https://i.stack.imgur.com/35vDQ.png`

`Situation shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA1N9.png`

I have tried multiple ways of extracting fields from the main field, but there is no way to do that, because i can not split this json into ROWS.
I can split each json object into different field, but that does not help, because, apparently, you cant transform fields to rows for JSON format.